# How to print the number of occurrences of consonants for each file separately with awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to count the **occurrences of consonants** in **multiple files**,
but I want the number of occurrences to be separately calculated for each file. 
I use

```
awk -v FS="" '{for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~/[bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNPQRTSVWXYZ]/) count_c++}} END {print FILENAME,count_c}' file1 file2
```

file1 looks like this:

```
bac Dfeg           
k87 eH

tRe        
rt up
```

file2 looks like this:

```
hi
rt2w
Prt
```

but it prints the occurrences of both files (output=`file2 19`). How could I change this so the output would be like:

```
file1 12
file2 7
```

Comment: Do you have GNU awk (`gawk`)? if so, you can use `ENDFILE` in place of `END` (and add a `BEGINFILE` rule to reset the counter)

Comment: @steeldriver no I don't have it:(((,could it somehow be done with awk?

Comment: @steeldriver I tried gawk -v FS="" 'BEGINFILE{for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~/[bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNPQRTSVWXYZ]/) count_c++}} ENDFILE {print FILENAME,count_c}' file1 file2  but it isn't doing anything

Comment: @pleasehelp the `BEGINFILE` rule only needs to reset the counter. The actual matching/counting needs to remain in a separate rule that is applied to all records, like you originally had it.

Comment: @steeldriver so where exactly should I put the BEGINFILE ?because everything I tried didn't work

Comment: The command you showed under "for the following code (provided by Ed Morton):" would take the strings `file1 and `file2` as input to the script, not as the names of file names containing input to the script, it cannot produce the output you say it does. Please [edit] your question to show **exactly** the command you ran so we can help you.

Comment: If you fix that though to have the file names listed as arguments as shown in my answer then it's impossible for that script to print a `0` because the only print statement is printing 2 values at a time, a file name and a count, and even if the file name was somehow null (which it isn't), there would still be a space before the count. I'm sorry but what you say is happening 100% cannot happen as a result of running my script. You must have something else you're doing to print that first `0`.

Comment: (1) You listed `t` and `s` in the wrong order. That doesn't matter, but the fact that you listed `E` as a consonant is an error.  (2) I agree with @EdMorton on two levels.  (2a) It is totally impossible for the command that you show to produce the output you show. For it to have ***any** chance* of working, the file names would have to be on the same command line as the `awk` command.  (2b) Even if you fix that error, it should not be producing the `0`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Please [edit] your question again to show exactly what you are running and what you are getting.  If you are really getting output similar to what you show, please run ``awk -V`` (or ``awk --version``) and tell us what *that* says.  (It's conceivable that you might get unexpected, non-conformant results from `awk` if you are running a sufficiently old, brain-damaged version of it.)

Comment: If any of the answers solves your problem then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next, otherwise provide feedback and/or questions about any issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE and IGNORECASE:

```
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    { cnt += ( gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"&") - gsub(/[aeiou]/,"&") )}
    ENDFILE { print FILENAME, cnt+0; cnt=0 }
' file1 file2
file1 12
file2 7
```

or with any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '
    { lc=tolower($0); cnt[FILENAME] += (gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"&",lc) - gsub(/[aeiou]/,"&",lc)) }
    END { for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) print ARGV[i], cnt[ARGV[i]]+0 }
' file1 file2
file1 12
file2 7
```

If you only want to count the specific characters b, c, d, etc. instead of all alphabetic characters that aren't aeiou, then just change `( gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"&") - gsub(/[aeiou]/,"&") )` above to `gsub(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyz]/,"&"))`

Note that, unlike any approach that prints results in an `FNR==1` clause, both of the above scripts will handle empty files correctly by printing the file name and 0 as the count.

Also note the `cnt+0` in the first script - the `+0` ensures that the value printed will be a numeric `0` rather than a null string if the first file is empty.

If the same file name can appear multiple times in the input then  add `FNR==1{cnt[FILENAME]=0}` to the start of the script if you want it output multiple times or add `if (!seen[ARGV[i]]++) { ... }` around the print in the END section if you only want it output once.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642372/133219 for an answer to the followup question of also counting vowels.

Comment: No script in my answer does that so you'd have to show me (again, in your question, not in a comment) what script you actually ran for me to be able to tell you why it did that. Or just run exactly the script in my answer and then it won't do that.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, and probably not much, I'd be tempted to do this without `awk`:

```
consonants=bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyz
for f in file*; do
    printf "%s %d\n" "$f" "$(< "$f" tr A-Z a-z | tr -dc "$consonants"  | wc -c)"
done
```

Though that, of course, is quite ASCII-centric (and if you have GNU tr, it doesn't deal with multibyte characters anyway.)

Comment: maybe expound on the ASCII-centric vs. multibyte chars just a bit, to clarify the benefits or shortcomings of this approach