# How to print the number of occurrences of consonants and vowels for each file with awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to count the **occurrences of consonants and vowels** in **multiple files** on Linux, but I want the number of occurrences to be separately calculated for each file. I use

```
awk -v FS=""'{for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~/[bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNPQRTSVWXYZ]/)cout_c++ ;else if ($i ~/[aeiouAEIOU]/) count_v++}}END {print  FILENAME,count_v,count_c}'
```

file1 looks like this:

```
bac Dfeg            
k87 eH

tRe
rt up
```

file2 looks like this:

```
hi
rt2w
PrOt
```

but it prints the occurrences of both files:

```
file2 7 19
```

How could I change this so the output would be like :

```
file1  5 12
file2  2 7
```

Comment: If the input contains a U+FB03 character (`ﬃ`), should it be counted as 2 consonants and 1 vowel?

Comment: no, just these characters bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNPQRTSVWXYZ should be counted for consonants and for vowels aeiouAEIOU anything else should be ignored

Comment: Again, please don't add requirements as comments. Make sure all of your requirements are clearly stated in your question and included in your sample input/output.

Comment: Crossposting? [How to print with awk the number of consonants and vowels from files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66832823/3776858)

Comment: If any of the answers solves your problem then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next, otherwise provide feedback and/or questions about any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer this [followup question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/642359/133219), here is my [followup answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642367/133219) with GNU awk (and modified now to only count b, c, d, etc. as non-vowels instead of every char that's not aeiou, e.g. `À` and `é` as mentioned by [@StéphaneChazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) in a comment):

```
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    {
        v_cnt += gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")
        c_cnt += gsub(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyz]/,"")
    }
    ENDFILE {
        print FILENAME, v_cnt+0, c_cnt+0
        v_cnt = c_cnt = 0
    }
' file1 file2
file1 5 12
file2 2 7
```

I'll leave it as a simple exercise for how to modify the POSIX awk equivalent from my previous answer.

If you also wanted some kind of indication if alphabetic characters not listed in either of the bracket expressions above are present then it's just a tweak to:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    {
        v_cnt += gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")
        c_cnt += gsub(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyz]/,"")
    }
    /[[:alpha:]]/ {
        gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/,"")
        printf "Warning %s[%d]: Unexpected chars found: %s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0 > "/dev/stderr"
    }
    ENDFILE {
        print FILENAME, v_cnt+0, c_cnt+0
        v_cnt = c_cnt = 0
    }
' file1 file2
```

How that's handled can of course be treated in various different ways and with various amounts+details of output.

Comment: Note that `[[:alpha:]]` would match on `À`, `é` (if expressed in their precomposed form which is the most common), `α`, etc that haven't been removed by the previous `gsub()`.

Comment: That's true. If such characters can exist in the input then the OP should add  them to the sample input/output in the question so we can see how they should be handled.

Comment: if i write instead of [[:alpha:]]-> [bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNPQRTSVWXYZ] than that would solve this problem right?

Comment: Just `[bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyz]` - you don't need to list the upper case letters since we're doing a case-insensitive comparison. But then how SHOULD letters like `À` and `é` be counted if they can exist in your input - as vowels or as consonants or as punctuation (i.e. not alphabetic characters) or something else? If they can exist in  your real data then please edit your question to include them in the sample input and the counts shown in the expected output.

Comment: anything else than  aeiou for vowels and bcdfghjklmnpqrtsvwxyz for consonants should be ignored.Could you also tell me for what v_cnt+0 is needed, I don't understand the adding with 0?

Comment: @pleasehelp I already explained that in my answer to your previous question, please read that.

Comment: Just to clarify here with paraphrasing [the previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642367/27776): the`+0` in `cnt+0` "ensures that the value printed will be a numeric 0 rather than a null string if the...file is empty."

Comment: Note that `echo I | LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8 gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{print gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")}'` returns 0 as uppercase `i` is `İ` there and lowercase `I` is `ı`.

Comment: Good point, I'll leave it to the OP to decide if that's correct behavior or not and, if not, if it's something they need to consider handling in their code.

Answer (score 2):

One way using **Perl** is as follows:

```
perl -lne '$,=" ";
    $A[0] += +lc =~ tr/aeiou//;
    $A[1] += s/(?![aeiou])[[:alpha:]]//gi;
    print $ARGV, splice @A if eof;
' file1 file2
```

**Output:**

```
file1 5 12
file2 2 7
```

Comments;

- First element of an array @A accumulates the running total of vowels.
- The second element accumulates the running total of consonants, which are alphabet set minus vowels.
- At the end of present file, the data is dumped.Note splice as a side effect nulls the array.